# Remove Site Logo from Homepage in Twenty Twentyone

Tags: logo, theme-twenty-twenty-one

I am looking for a way not to show the site logo in my homepage (but on all other pages). I can manage to do this only in the nasty way, using css and display none - however, I would like to avoid that the logo is not loaded on the homepage? functions.php?

best, Aprilia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it like this, it works, but seems not very elegant?

```
function change_logo_on_front($html) {

if(is_front_page()){
      $html = preg_replace('/<img(.*?)\/>/', ' ', $html);
   }
   return $html;
}

add_filter('get_custom_logo','change_logo_on_front');
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a quick look at the [site-branding template part](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwentyone/1.3/template-parts/header/site-branding.php) which handles the rendering of the custom logo on the site header. There's a conditional check on two lines against `has_custom_logo()`, along show title theme mod, which determines, if the custom logo should be rendered or not.

Internally `has_custom_logo()` calls `get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' )` to figure out, if a custom logo has been set. This means, you can use the [theme_mod_{$name}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_mod_name/) filter to change 1) the value of the theme mod and 2) the result of `has_custom_logo()`.

As code the above would be something like this,

```
function prefix_disable_logo_on_front_page( $value ) {
    return is_front_page() ? false : $value;
}
add_filter('theme_mod_custom_logo', 'prefix_disable_logo_on_front_page');
```

Comment: thank you, Anti Koskinen

Answer (score 3):

You can add the below condition in the header.php file just above the img tag:

```
<?php if(!is_front_page()){?>
<img src="your_image_path">
<?php } ?>
```